# Null values inside @PreAuthorize giving error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to check if the user has role "ADMIN" and if he is the project's creator before giving him access to change the project like this:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and this.projectService.findById(#id).getAdmin().getUsername() == authentication.name")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> doUpdateProject(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ProjectDto project) 
        throws InstanceNotFoundException, DuplicatedResourceException {        
        Project updatedProject = projectService.update(id, project.getName(), project.getDescription());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedProject);
    }
```

This works, only allowing an admin to update the project if he is the owner. But I noticed that if I make the call to a non-existent project, I get a 500 Internal Server Error instead of a 404 Not Found:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/tasks-service] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and this.projectService.findById(#id).getAdmin().getUsername() == authentication.name'] with root cause.
```

I think that it is because of pointing to a null value (projectService.findById(#id)) but even when checking if the value is null, using for example a ternary operator that returns "true" if the value is null, I keep getting the same error.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and this.projectService.findById(#id) != null ? this.projectService.findById(#id)?.getAdmin().getUsername() == authentication.name : true")
```

My idea here is to "pass" the @PreAuthorize condition when the project ID specified does not exist in order to get a 404 error later, but the same internal error is happening.

What should I do to get a 404 Not Found in this case?

Comment: maybe check that id is not null?

Comment: Are you certain `this.projectService.findById(#id)` return `null` when the project ID doesn't exist. Is it possible it throws an exception instead?